# Firebase security rules, data variable

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database schema like this:

- Posts

  - unverified

    - post_1
    - post_2
      ...

And here is a shortened list of data in /posts/unverified path

```
{
  "-L7xmY2HMeEImDZnZqTf" : {
    "categorie" : 0,
    "commonFields" : {...},
    "fbKey" : "-L7YM7vEf8RpcxGUTpDE",
    "images" : [...],
    "specialFields" : {
      "area" : "150",
      "productPrice" : {
        "currency" : "dollar",
        "value" : "65000"
      },
      "requestType" : "sell",
      "requesterType" : "personal",
      "roomCount" : 3,
      "suburbia" : "false"
    },
    "subCat" : 0,
    "timestamp" : 1521011840178,
    "uid" : "Fo5f6VonWgQVpsf6u80TPgoi2it2"
  },
  "-L7YNUZPL1-Dl7EhScEE" : {...},
  "-L7YNUZPL1-fdfasfa" : {...},
  "-L7YNUZPL1-ljljklfd" : {...},
  "-L7YNUZPL1-lkjlkjfas" : {...},
}
```

And a firebase security rules defined as below

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "unverified": {
        ".indexOn": "timestamp",
        ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

As the rules show, I want to read unverified posts if the users id equal to the uid field in the post data

But every time i use the rules simulator ( or test the with the codes ) with the below configuration, its' giving `Simulated read denied` error

[image]

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Please edit your post to show the actual JSON (as text, no screenshot) at `/posts/unverified`. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I just updated the post Frank..

Comment: That post does not have a `uid` property with the UID you're testing with. That would indeed make the simulator fail.

Comment: It does have a uid exactly with UID im testing with. Its why im asking here. The post im testing has a key `-L7xmY2HMeEImDZnZqTf` and that post has uid property `Fo5f6VonWgQVpsf6u80TPgoi2it2` .. And i test `posts/unverified/-L7xmY2HMeEImDZnZqTf` path with `Fo5f6VonWgQVpsf6u80TPgoi2it2` uid

Comment: Ah wait, I see it now. You're missing a level in your rules. I'll write an example in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. it works now :)

Comment: I have read firebase  documentation multiple time and couldn't find an example close to my use case.. 
I think its better to include more example in the doc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167531/discussion-between-fakhruddin-abdi-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.read` rule is defined on `/posts/unverified` and checks a child called `uid`. So the total path is `/posts/unverified/uid`.

You're trying to read `/posts/unverified/-L7xmY2HMeEImDZnZqTf`. And the UID value is defined on `/posts/unverified/-L7xmY2HMeEImDZnZqTf/uid`.

The two paths don't match. You need to add a wildcard in your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "unverified": {
        ".indexOn": "timestamp",
        "$postid": {
          ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

Comment: Are you sure we should put ` ".indexOn": "timestamp",` inside $postid block instead of its parent block ? eg : ` "unverified": {`

Comment: Good one, I moved it back up. But your problem in the emulator (and in the code) was caused by having `.read` one level too high.